# Is there a way to make this a a cleaner or better looking algorithm? (Grade/Average calculator)

Tags: python

So I made this mental math quiz, besides the point. but I want to make a percent/average of the grade the person would get on the quiz. So I wrote this out, and it works. But it is for a project and I want it to look more presentable than it does right now. Thanks in advance.

```
score = 5
score2 = 5

def calcGrade():
    global score
    global score2
    grade = score + score2 
    grading = grade / 10
    gradinge = grading * 100
    print("your grade is",gradinge)

calcGrade()
```

and don't worry, global variables are allowed.

Comment: You'll have better luck posting to codereview.stackexchange.com. Unfortunately this is off-topic here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: As @DavidMakogon suggested, not for SO. However, if "global variables are allowed" and all your function does is add two numbers together and multiply by 10 to print the result, I doubt you'll get much useful feedback either way.